# Is the streaming package's Stream data type equivalent to FreeT?

Tags: haskell, stream, monad-transformers, free-monad

The [streaming](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming) package defines a [`Stream`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-0.2.1.0/docs/src/Streaming-Internal.html#Stream) type that looks like the following:

```
data Stream f m r
  = Step !(f (Stream f m r))
 | Effect (m (Stream f m r))
 | Return r
```

There is a comment on the `Stream` type that says the following:

> The `Stream` data type is equivalent to [`FreeT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-5.0.2/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Free.html) and can represent any effectful succession of steps, where the form of the steps or 'commands' is specified by the first (functor) parameter.

I'm wondering how the `Stream` type is equivalent to `FreeT`?

Here is the definition of `FreeT`:

```
data FreeF f a b = Pure a | Free (f b)
newtype FreeT f m a = FreeT { runFreeT :: m (FreeF f a (FreeT f m a)) }
```

It looks like it is not possible to create an isomorphism between these two types.

To be specific, I don't see a way to write the following two functions that makes them an isomorphism:

```
freeTToStream :: FreeT f m a -> Stream f m a
streamToFreeT :: Stream f m a -> FreeT f m a
```

For instance, I'm not sure how to express a value like `Return "hello" :: Stream f m String` as a `FreeT`.

I guess it could be done like the following, but the `Pure "hello"` is necessarily going to be wrapped in an `m`, while in `Return "hello" :: Stream f m String` it is not:

```
FreeT $ pure $ Pure "hello" :: Applicative m => FreeT f m a
```

---

Can `Stream` be considered equivalent to `FreeT` even though it doesn't appear possible to create an isomorphism between them?

Comment: Here is some [code](https://github.com/cdepillabout/LambdaJAM-Streaming-exercises/blob/54af869b7d1211b7be5aafb76b1d8d7bba9f2ae7/exercise_1/LambdaJAM/Streaming/Exercise1.hs#L234-L336) trying to implement the isomorphism between `FreeT` and `Stream` (which is called `FStream` in the code).  This should make it easy for anyone that wants to play around with this.  This code is from Ivan Miljenovic's [workshop](https://github.com/ivan-m/LambdaJAM-Streaming-exercises) on the streaming library at Lambda Jam 2018.

Comment: It's certainly not possible to implement an isomorphism between those types. `FreeT (Const ()) IO ()` has no equivalent of `foo :: Stream (Const ()) IO () ; foo = Effect $ putStrLn "hello world" >> pure foo`. What might be possible is showing that every `Stream` is equivalent to *some* `FreeT` over a different functor/monad pair.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some small differences that make them not literally equivalent. In particular, `FreeT` enforces an alternation of `f` and `m`,

```
FreeT f m a = m (Either a (f (FreeT f m a) = m (Either a (f (m (...))))
                                          -- m            f  m  -- alternating
```

whereas `Stream` allows stuttering, e.g., we can construct the following with no `Step` between two `Effect`:

```
Effect (return (Effect (return (Return r))))
```

which should be equivalent *in some sense* to

```
Return r
```

Thus we shall take a quotient of `Stream` by the following equations that flatten the layers of `Effect`:

```
Effect (m >>= \a -> return (Effect (k a))) = Effect (m >>= k)
Effect (return x) = x
```

Under that quotient, the following are isomorphisms

```
freeT_stream :: (Functor f, Monad m) => FreeT f m a -> Stream f m a
freeT_stream (FreeT m) = Effect (m >>= \case
  Pure r -> return (Return r)
  Free f -> return (Step (fmap freeT_stream f))

stream_freeT :: (Functor f, Monad m) => Stream f m a -> FreeT f m a
stream_freeT = FreeT . go where
  go = \case
    Step f -> return (Free (fmap stream_freeT f))
    Effect m -> m >>= go
    Return r -> return (Pure r)
```

Note the `go` loop to flatten multiple `Effect` constructors.

---

Pseudoproof: `(freeT_stream . stream_freeT) = id`

We proceed by induction on a stream `x`. To be honest, I'm pulling the induction hypotheses out of thin air. There are certainly cases where induction is not applicable. It depends on what `m` and `f` are, and there might also be some nontrivial setup to ensure this approach makes sense for a quotient type. But there should still be many concrete `m` and `f` where this scheme is applicable. I hope there is some categorical interpretation that translates this pseudoproof to something meaningful.

```
(freeT_stream . stream_freeT) x
= freeT_stream (FreeT (go x))
= Effect (go x >>= \case
    Pure r -> return (Return r)
    Free f -> return (Step (fmap freeT_stream f)))
```

Case `x = Step f`, induction hypothesis (IH) `fmap (freeT_stream . stream_freeT) f = f`:

```
= Effect (return (Step (fmap freeT_stream (fmap stream_freeT f))))
= Effect (return (Step f))  -- by IH
= Step f  -- by quotient
```

Case `x = Return r`

```
= Effect (return (Return r))
= Return r   -- by quotient
```

Case `x = Effect m`, induction hypothesis `m >>= (return . freeT_stream . stream_freeT)) = m`

```
= Effect ((m >>= go) >>= \case ...)
= Effect (m >>= \x' -> go x' >>= \case ...)  -- monad law
= Effect (m >>= \x' -> return (Effect (go x' >>= \case ...)))  -- by quotient
= Effect (m >>= \x' -> (return . freeT_stream . stream_freeT) x')  -- by the first two equations above in reverse
= Effect m  -- by IH
```

---

Converse left as an exercise.

Comment: I think this answer could be clearer with a little more metaphor: `FreeT f m` represents alternating layers of `m` and `f`. `Stream f m` represents layers of `m` and `f` in any order. As long as `Monad m`, we have `pure` to create `m` layers wherever we want and `join` to fuse them. Therefore, a `Stream f m` is an "efficient" representation of `FreeT f m` that can be converted to the more rigid form if required.

Answer (score 4):

Both your example with `Return` and my example with nested `Effect` constructors cannot be represented by `FreeT` with the same parameters `f` and `m`. There are more counterexamples, too. The underlying difference in the data types can best be seen in a hand-wavey space where the data constructors are stripped out and infinite types are allowed.

Both `Stream f m a` and `FreeT f m a` are for nesting an `a` type inside a bunch of `f` and `m` type constructors. `Stream` allows arbitrary nesting of `f` and `m`, while `FreeT` is more rigid. It always has an outer `m`. That contains either an `f` and another `m` and repeats, or an `a` and terminates.

But that doesn't mean there isn't an equivalence of some sort between the types. You can show some equivalence by showing that each type can be embedded inside the other faithfully.

Embedding a `Stream` inside a `FreeT` can be done on the back of one observation: if you choose an `f'` and `m'` such that the `f` and `m` type constructors are optional at each level, you can model arbitrary nesting of `f` and `m`. One quick way to do that is use `Data.Functor.Sum`, then write a function:

```
streamToFreeT :: Stream f m a -> FreeT (Sum Identity f) (Sum Identity m) a
streamToFreeT = undefined -- don't have a compiler nearby, not going to even try
```

Note that the type won't have the necessary instances to function. That could be corrected by switching `Sum Identity` to a more direct type that actually has an appropriate `Monad` instance.

The transformation back the other direction doesn't need any type-changing trickery. The more restricted shape of `FreeT` is already directly embeddable inside `Stream`.

I'd say this makes the documentation correct, though possibly it should use a more precise term than "equivalent". Anything you can construct with one type, you can construct with the other - but there might be some extra interpretation of the embedding and a change of variables involved.